# Google Sheets - return range of all rows containing value

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need to collect all rows containing a certain value at column a. I want to use the result to paste it into a `CountIf` filter:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A4, "Pete")      (A1:A4 should be generated dynamically)
```

The table looks something like this:

[image]

Any idea on how I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you want to do, but if it is to count the occurrences of a name in column A, put the name to find in B2 and this in C2:

```
=countif(A:A,B2)
```